# How to get the interceipt from model summary in Python linearmodels?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, linearmodels

I am running a panel reggression using Python `linearmodels`, something like:

```
import pandas as pd
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')
data = data.set_index(['panel_id', 'date'])
controls = ['A','B','C']
controls['const'] = 1
model = PanelOLS(data.Y, controls, entity_effects= True)
result = model.fit(use_lsdv=True)
```

I really need to pull out the coefficient on the constant, but looks like this would not work

```
intercept = result.summary.const
```

Could not really find the answer in
[linearmodels' documentation on github](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/panel/models.html)
More generally, does anyone know how to pull out the estimate coefficients from the `linearmodels` summary? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result.params['const']`

would give the intercept, in general `result.params` gives the series of regression coefficients in `linearmodels`